# Check if file is finished copying when using watchdog

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I'm using [watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/) to watch a folder for new files.

When I copy a file to the watched directory, the watchdog triggers 4 times.

- FileCreatedEvent - when the copy initiates
- DirModifiedEvent - at the same time as FileCreatedEvent
- FileModifiedEvent - when the transfer begins
- FileModifiedEvent - when the transfer finishes

Is there a way to tell when the transfer has finished so it only works on files that are finished copying and doesn't attempt to process an incomplete file?

Comment: Not if there's no `FileClosedEvent`

Comment: The usual solution to problems like this is to copy the file into a temporary name or folder that you're not watching. After it finishes copying there, it renames to the file that the watchdog looks for. Rename is atomic.